# Open Git with child_process.execFile as administrator

Tags: node.js, git, child-process

I want to execute Git programatically with node but with administrator privileges in windows 10.

I know how to start it without admin privileges:

```
const execFile = util.promisify(require('child_process').execFile);

async function _startGit() {
  await execFile("C:\\Program Files\\Git\\git-bash.exe");
}
```

and then call the function _startGit()

But what I need to add to get a Git Console started with administrator privileges in Windows 10?

Thanks

Comment: Does using `child_process.exec` instead, along with the windows [`runas`](https://ss64.com/nt/runas.html) command help at all?

Comment: Hi  J. Titus.  Can you give an example please?

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work, but `require('child_process').exec` and something like `exec("runas /profile /user:administrator C:\\Program Files\\Git\\git-bash.exe")` ...maybe?